# JQuery Masonry animation doesn't load from bottom

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

On my WordPress site the Masonry script is included in my functions.php and Infinite-Scroll is  activated with the plugin. Looks like everything is working (although elements overlap sometimes).

But new appended elements are animated from top left, instead from the bottom.

This is the callback in WP admin:

```
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
```

The last 'true' means 'isAnimatedFromBottom', not?

Demo site: http://goo.gl/9XVIl

Answer (score 0):

There's [a bug in masonry v2](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/249) that prevents the `isAnimatedFromBottom` parameter from working with CSS transitions.

You have a few options.

1. Switch to JS animation using the `isAnimated: true` option. But the animation may be slow.
2. Patch the code using the code in suggested in the [issue](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/249).